# Is there a penalty for wrongly marking a post as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support, duplicate-questions, vote-to-reopen

An incorrect duplicate tag on a post effectively discourages other members from reading it or responding to it. Until it gets reopened (I am guessing the time taken to do so is dependent on how long the reopen queue is), the post will be ignored.

I am trying to understand if stackoverflow penalizes members for wrongly marking a post as a duplicate. Are they docked off some reputation points for doing so ?

To be honest , i may have been guilty of this on a few occasions. In cases where you see two post with similar titles the first instinct is to mark it as duplicate. My limited point is how does the forum motivate members to read the entire post and think long enough before arriving at a decision.

Recently , [one of my posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30791024/effectively-debugging-log4j-framework) was marked as a duplicate.

One post talks about issues with logging applications messages with debug level (logging levels). My own post talks about being able to effectively debug log4j framework itself. To me its not quite clear how the two are related.

I don't want to make this all about a single post. For all i know , I may be wrong in this case.

I am just wondering if there are sufficient checks and balances in the system for avoiding misuse or abuse of this feature.

Comment: Checks and balances are different to penalising people, which are you after? There is a balance as people who can close can reopen, but I'm not sure how or why you would attempt to punish someone for taking the "wrong" decision. How do you determine who was wrong?

Comment: There isn't any benefit to marking a question as a duplicate for no reason, and flagging a question as a duplicate normally requires multiple votes.  However, persons with gold badges in a particular tag (very difficult, 1000 score for at least 200 answers in that tag) can singlehandedly mark duplicates.  I doubt that they went through that much effort just to randomly mark duplicates, and suspect that this was probably an errant mistake.  However, you are welcome to flag the question for moderator review.

Comment: @Ben I was assuming the two would be related. In this case just like you have pointed out , I have voted to reopen the post. Lets assume the post gets 4 additional votes ,  it would no longer be considered a duplicate. Would the member who originally marked it duplicate then be penalized ?

Comment: no, they wouldn't be penalized; they didn't receive anything positive for the action that could be taken away.  People aren't perfect, and it's reasonable to assume that it's possible that someone might be incorrect in their judgment, which is why there is a reopen option.

Comment: @Claies At no point I am suggesting that the member did this with malicious intent. But what the duplicate tag on this post effectively did was that it discouraged other members form reading or responding to it. Until its get reopened , I am guessing there will be a long reopen queue , the post will be continue to be ignored. If there is no form of penalty or check here then to me it indicates an imbalance of sorts.

Comment: Leaving the comment that you don't believe it's a dupe is good but you should, either in the comment or in the post itself, state ***why*** it's not a duplicate. If you can make that obvious, then you will have a better shot at people reopening it (possibly even the closer himself). I have closed posts single handedly and had someone edit with details and explanations as to *why* it wasn't a dupe and I reopened.

Comment: again, there is no imbalance;  It takes a considerable amount of effort to earn the positive reputation necessary to single-handedly close questions.  That power is not given to make it easier for someone to stop you from getting an answer, it's given to people who have demonstrated *extensive* knowledge of the tagged subject, to enable them to moderate the subject they have shown frequent participation in.  Still, mistakes happen, and using the Re-Open queue or flagging the post is your best course to correct the error.

Comment: That user has a very long history of bad closures. I've reopened. But, yeah, do what everyone else suggested.

Comment: Is there a reward for correctly marking a post as duplicate? (Hint: [no, there isn't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90620/reward-finding-duplicate-questions-10-2-5).)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a penalty for wrongly marking a post as duplicate?

No, not really. Unless a user has shown to misuse voting power in some way and is brought to the attention of mod/employee and they agree that the user has been closing many things as dup's that are definitely not dup's, they could decide to act upon it in some way. But for one-off scenarios and infrequent cases, nothing will be done or should be done.

So if you notice your question or someone else's question was wrongly closed as a dup, you should just edit the question and explain why it's not a dup of that question it was closed as a dup of. Then vote to reopen (if you can). Your edit will send the question to the Reopen queue where other users will determine if the question should be reopened or not.